# Is EBNF considered as a Programming Language

Tags: programming-languages, bnf, ebnf

I am confused wheter EBNF can be considered as a Programming language which is turing complete?

Comment: How could it be? EBNF does not describe computations or algorithms.

Comment: I know but how can we prove it formaly?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, no, [Extended Backus–Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) (EBNF) is not a programming language. It is a metasyntax notation.

While a language is a way to describe an algorithm (what a computer should do), metasyntax is a way to describe a language.